# How do I envoke a MSBuild target in the middle of another target?

Tags: msbuild

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
<Target Name="DoStuff" >
    <Message Text="Doing stuff..." />
    //run target DoOtherThing
    <Message Text="Doing more stuff..." />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [CallTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229474.aspx) which you'd use like

```
<Target Name="DoStuff" >
  <Message Text="Doing stuff..." />
  <CallTarget Targets="DoOtherThing" />
  <Message Text="Doing more stuff..." />
</Target>
```

and there's the more idiomatic, albeit a bit over the top for this case, way:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MyTargets Include="Message1" />
  <MyTargets Include="DoOtherThing" />
  <MyTargets Include="Message2" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Message1" />
  <Message Text="Doing stuff..." />
</Target>

<Target Name="DoOtherThing" />
  <CallTarget Targets="DoOtherThing" />
</Target>

<Target Name="Message2" />
  <Message Text="Doing more stuff..." />
</Target>

<Target Name="DoStuff" DependsOnTargets="@(MyTargets)">
</Target>
```

Comment: :) these two ways aren't equivalent - DependsOn will call all the targets before DoStuff, not in the middle. Also it won't have access to  DoStuff's scoped properties and items. But CallTarget on opposite side is not MSBuild-style.

Comment: Well but DoStuff itself is just an empty stub, so they are equivalent: both cases result in Message/DoOtherThing/Message

Comment: In this particular case - yes, but it's "theory", in practice question author probably will run it in more realistic conditions where these two things aren't the same (moreover -idiomatic way will execute target only once, and call target will execute it on each call). But I agree - it's a nitpicking :)

Comment: I can certainly see a use for both patterns.